# How do I query an appengine datastore with an email address

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to lookup users in appengine datastore using their email address.  I'm using Go.

This code finds no users.

```
var users []entity.User
q := datastore.NewQuery("users").Filter("AccountEmail =", "email@address.com")
_, err := q.GetAll(c, &users)
```

If I change the query to lookup the user with the "Id" property instead it works fine.

```
var users []entity.User
q := datastore.NewQuery("users").Filter("Id", "185804764220139124118")
_, err := q.GetAll(c, &users)
```

I've confirmed the property name and value for "AccountEmail" is correct.  "AccountEmail" It is indexed too.

Is there some special formatting that needs to be done with an email address to get the query to work?

Comment: Is it stored as a string or something else like byte slice?

Comment: @fredrik - "AccountEmail" is stored as a string.

Comment: @Thundercat - I have confirmed in datastore viewer that the "users" entity does exist and the property name "AccountEmail" exists.

Comment: are you sure there is no spaces or something? what output do you get if you do `fmt.Printf("%#v", users)` when you get it via the id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to find the user by email (`AccountEmail`), all of the following conditions must be true. Please check and ensure each "test" passes:

- An entity with property name `AccountEmail` must exists. Don't forget that the property name is case-sensitive. Note that the datastore name and the `struct` field name may be different, tags can be used to change it, e.g.

  `` AccountEmail string `datastore:"email"` ``
- The property must be indexed. Note that whether a property is indexed may vary from entity to entity, so you may have an entity where `AccountEmail` is indexed and another one where `AccountEmail` is not indexed.
- `AccountEmail` must have a type `string`. I assume this is trivial and is so. But note that it is possible to save a property with the `User` type which is different from the `string` type and when you list entities in the Datastore viewer for example, the email will be displayed just like if it would be an email string, but obviously it is different.
- To find the user with `AccountEmail="email@address.com"`, the value saved must be `"email@address.com"` exactly. Lower and upper case letters are different! Spaces (and all whitespace characters) matter! Please check if the saved value is exactly this as you will not see trailing spaces when printed for example, but they will cause a mismatch! Also some unicode characters have the same visual appearance (they look the same) but their unicode codepoint is not the same and will also cause a mismatch.

Comment: Your final point was the correct one in my case.  The data was coming in from a url parameter and there was a slight typo in the url which caused a difference I couldn't see visually.   Thank you