# AppEngine Datastore query with filter never returns results (Go)

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

If I don't use a filter, I get results. If I use a filter (this record definitely exists), I don't get any results. It might be the lack of an index defined for that property, but, as I understand it, simple indices should automatically be created in the development server (and an index.yaml file created and populated with it). This is not happening.

```
query = datastore.NewQuery("UserAccount").Filter("email =", "test@example.com")

ua := UserAccount{}
t := query.Run(ctx)
for ; ; {
    if _, err = t.Next(&ua); err == nil {
        log.Debugf(ctx, "Current: %s", ua)
    } else if err == datastore.Done {
        break
    } else {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

When the development server terminates, it states that it's "saving search indexes":

```
INFO     2016-08-08 05:09:52,894 api_server.py:651] Saving search indexes
```

However, since an "index.yaml" file doesn't appear, I'm assuming that no indices needed to be created, which means that my query must not've had the desired effect?

What am I missing?

Edit:

Note that the record was previously created and the application stopped and started many times since. I sincerely doubt this is a eventual-consistency thing.

Edit 2:

For the purpose of testing, I've created the following model with the following code. They both exhibit the same behavior as my original model and code.

Definition:

```
type TestEntity struct {
    Email string
}
```

Code:

```
log.Debugf(ctx, "Putting.")

email := "anothertest@a.b"

te := &TestEntity{
        Email: email,
}

k := datastore.NewKey(ctx, "TestEntity", "123", 0, nil)
_, err = datastore.Put(ctx, k, te)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

log.Debugf(ctx, "Waiting.")
time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)

query := datastore.NewQuery("TestEntity")

var results []TestEntity
_, err = query.GetAll(ctx, &results)
log.Debugf(ctx, "GetAll: %s", results)

log.Debugf(ctx, "Running query.")

query = datastore.NewQuery("TestEntity").Filter("email =", email)

te = &TestEntity{}
t := query.Run(ctx)
for ; ; {
    if _, err = t.Next(te); err == nil {
        log.Debugf(ctx, "Found: [%s]", te.Email)
    } else if err == datastore.Done {
        log.Debugf(ctx, "Done.")
        break
    } else {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Results:

```
2016/08/09 02:11:36 DEBUG: Putting.
2016/08/09 02:11:36 DEBUG: Waiting.
2016/08/09 02:11:37 DEBUG: GetAll: [{anothertest@a.b}]
2016/08/09 02:11:37 DEBUG: Running query.
2016/08/09 02:11:37 DEBUG: Done.
```

Screenshot of Viewer:

[image: Screenshot of Viewer]

Comment: It is because of **eventual consistency**. See possible duplicates: 1. [How to filter a GAE query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29228712/how-to-filter-a-gae-query); 2. [Google App Engine Datastore - Testing Queries fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28590519/google-app-engine-datastore-testing-queries-fails); 3. [Why the query doesn't return results when the ancestor is not provided?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29529296/why-the-query-doesnt-return-results-when-the-ancestor-is-not-provided)

Comment: Please confirm if this solves your issue.

Comment: @icza It doesn't. The record previously existed (read: prior to the current development-server being started). It was not just created.

Comment: Are you sure you have an exact `UserAccount` entity with `"email"` property having `"test@example.com"`? Please check my answer at this possible duplicate, and confirm if all tests pass: [How do I query an appengine datastore with an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29133079/how-do-i-query-an-appengine-datastore-with-an-email-address)

Comment: @icza Several good points, but none apply. I verified with a different record having a different value. This is ridiculous.

Comment: Please insert a `UserAccount` with `email="anothertest@a.b"`. Then insert a 1 second sleep, then please query by this email. Can you get the entity this way?

Comment: @icza Same as before. NewQuery->GetAll() returns it but a NewQuery->Filter->Run won't.

Comment: Please post your `UserAccount` type definition. Also please try the same with another type, e.g. `type Temp struct { Email string }`. Is your `UserAccount.email` unexported?

Comment: @icza It's exported. I could write it after all (it shows up in the Viewer). I created a new model and added that along with the code to the original post above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property name in the datastore is `"Email"` with capital E, not `"email"`.

It's case-sensitive, must be queried with capital E:

```
query = datastore.NewQuery("UserAccount").Filter("Email =", "test@example.com")
```

If you would want it to be saved / retrieved with small `e`, you could use [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373) to do the mapping, e.g.:

```
type UserAccount struct {
    Email string `datastore:"email"`
    // other fields...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing something that I was too dumb to notice myself. That was a fun thirty messages. At least we established the possibility of seeing the "unindexed" thing. Also, I got results but I still don't see any indices in the admin or an "index.yaml" file. As previously mentioned by DanCornilescu simple indices must never be represented (which seems like it'd make it harder to calculate cost estimates for writes). Lastly, I noticed when I run my AppEngine version under Go ("goapp serve"), I get a footnote that says it wraps the Python Dev server.

Comment: @DustinOprea Only composite indices needs to be added to `index.yaml`. Single property indices do not. Single property indices exist on a _per entity_ basis: one entity may have an indexed `Email` property, another one may have an unindexed `Email` property, a 3rd may not even have such property. And even a 4th may have one, but having different type... Datastore is not a relational database, it's schemaless.

Comment: @DustinOprea And yes, the Go SDK uses the python dev server, it's no secret.

Comment: I expected to not see an index.yaml file (it's already been mentioned by the user that I said mentioned it) but was stating it for posterity. I did, however, expect to see the simple index populate into the "Datastore Indexes" panel. I also meant to imply that, should you invoke the command-line help for the Java flavor, you might get the same indication (that it uses the Python server).

Comment: @DustinOprea Single property indices need not be defined explicitly, and they don't appear on the indices page. Only composite indices. There's no deviation here on the Go part. Property indices "just" exists and they just "vanish" if there is no entry for them.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to find an entity in the result of a query/filter by a property that property **must** have had indexing enabled (in the model definition) at the time when the entity was created and the datastore's background indexing task(s) must be completed for it.

If you enable indexing for that property **after** the entity was created you need to re-write the property so that the indexing tasks are triggered for it, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34583510/4495081.

The "Saving search indexes" message is a generic one printed before the operation takes place, it doesn't mean the result of the operation will be non-empty.

You don't need to worry that your `index.yaml` file is empty. Not all indexes need to be present in the `index.yaml` file, only the more complex/composite ones need to. Your filter can be matched using the built-in indexes (after the above-mentioned indexing requirements are met). From [Indexes](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes):

> There are two types of indexes:
>
> - *Built-in indexes*
>
>   By default, Cloud Datastore automatically predefines an index for each property of each entity kind. These single property indexes are
>     suitable for simple types of queries.
> - *Composite indexes*
>
>   Composite indexes index multiple property values per indexed entity. Composite indexes support complex queries and are defined in
>     an index configuration file (index.yaml).

Comment: It's not clear how to tag properties for indexing or if it's even supported. The documentation only mentions tagging in the context of *preventing* an index: (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/indexes) "Age  int `datastore:",noindex"`"

Comment: Indeed, go seems different than python in this regard. The answer still applies - you could have had indexing disabled when the entity was created :)

Comment: @DustinOprea: You can see if a property is indexed in your Cloud Console Datastore viewer. Find an entity and click on the edit icon - it will show all properties.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin I've never done a search on that column, but my understanding is that simple indices are implicitly created. However, that doesn't appear to be the case. I tried creating an *index.yaml* with some syntax errors to test whether or not it'd be loaded (if there were errors on startup then obviously there was an *attempt* to load it) and I could effectively add an explicit one there. However, the development environment seemed to completely ignore it on startup. Any ideas?

Comment: @DustinOprea I suspect the devserver only reads the `index.yaml` file when it encounters a query which needs a composite index - to check if an index needs to be added to the file. Try addind a composite query in your code just to test this theory - the devserver *should* either barf because of the incorrect existing `index.yaml` file or happily re-generate it from scratch if the theory is correct.

Comment: You don't need to specify an index for single properties. I have not used Go, but the convention in other runtimes is the same: property is indexed unless you request not to index it when an entity is created.

Comment: Note that you have to re-save the entity to make the property indexed - uploading index definitions will not affect any of the existing entities. You can, however, change a property to "indexed" in the Cloud Console manually (it does re-save it).

Comment: @AndreiVolgin There is no such option in the Dev Server Admin. The "Indexes" screen is empty of items and buttons and there is no ability to configure the entities/indexes in the query screen. You're saying this exists in production?

Comment: Yes, in production But the Dev Server should also show which properties are indexed (under the value - at least, in Java).

Comment: @AndreiVolgin I'm guessing that the Dev server is always Python, so I don't believe it'll make a difference. I added a screenshot of the Viewer. Is it in this screen that it should be indicated which properties are indexed? Note that since my indices appear to be troubled it may usually be shown but not at this moment.

Comment: My view looks different, but it may be because of the SDK version. I will try the latest.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Go, PHP, Python, and Java are currently essentially at the same version (1.9.40, my version) with the exception that Java is at 1.9.42 . The packaging may be language specific but I think they share the same Dev server (why rewrite it?).

Comment: Just tried 1.9.42. It looks different. There is no "Create entity" button. I feel cheated :)   I also see `(unindexed)` after values that are not indexed. Dan, you are a Python guy among us - what do you see?